# How to detect Automation Software on Production?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, frontend, cypress, end-to-end

We would like to detect and disable our service if automated test software(Cypress, Puppeteer) ) is running on our production software. How is it possible on front end?

[image]

Comment: Please provide more context. Why would you want to disable your service in production?

Comment: @natn2323 there is a typing competition going on on our website, we detected some cheaters are using such scripts from Cypress/puppeteer to cheat our software. That's why we would like to detect them and disable

Comment: When Cypress is running the app, you should see a `Cypress` property on the window object, see [Start tests when app is ready](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window.html#Start-tests-when-app-is-ready).

Comment: how about other automation? or chrome's flag `Chrome is being controlled by test software` how can I test this?